# Rails Row-Based Database, Huge Number of Requests

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

I designed a database that centers around short linked rows.

I have the following schema:

```
  create_table "students", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.boolean  "recruit",    default: true
    t.boolean  "archive",    default: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "fields", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "index"
    t.integer  "group_id"
    t.string   "description"
    t.string   "options"
    t.boolean  "hidden"
    t.boolean  "locked",      default: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "groups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "texts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "student_id"
    t.integer  "field_id"
    t.string   "content",    default: ""
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "options", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "student_id"
    t.integer  "field_id"
    t.string   "choice",     default: ""
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "addresses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "student_id"
    t.integer  "field_id"
    t.string   "address_1",  default: ""
    t.string   "address_2",  default: ""
    t.string   "city",       default: ""
    t.integer  "state_id",   default: 1
    t.string   "zip",        default: ""
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

The basis behind this organization was a fully flexible form. You simply add a new row to the field table, and that entry defines a new question on the form that generates students.  Group refers to an option field, text field, or address.  When the data is saved, the group associated with a given field tells my app which table to put it in.  This system works very well.  It's super flexible, I can easily see what students have data for certain options, and I can query based on nearly anything.

The problem is when I start to display students.  I first query on the students I wan to display, then I have to search for each field on each student.  This means that for 500 students, I have roughly 2500 queries on a basic form.  That kills performance.

I was wondering what the best way to join queries together and speed up this system is?

Part of the catch is that I cannot be 100% certain that a student has a given field, so when I query now, if the database returns no results, I am able to create one.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear as though you have any *foreign keys* defined here. A combination of using FKs and making sure they hit *indexes* on each table should allow for quick joins.

I assume you're using *ActiveRecord* based on *Rails* and the *DSL* in your question. I would recommend looking into using `joins` once you add your FKs. [ActiveRecord Querying doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

If you're concerned about certain `JOIN` columns not being present, you can use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (mentioned in the link above) in the call to `joins` such that you still get all the rows from the left-hand table even if there's no match on the join condition, and simply get `NULL` column values for the right-hand side. The ones which are `NULL` would tell you which ones don't exist and may need to be created subsequently.

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

I've not used the *SchemaPlus* gem myself, but I think that's fine to use for foreign keys if you want, given that's one of the things it supports (according to [its doc](https://github.com/SchemaPlus/schema_plus)).

Regarding this question:

> Like are there issues caused by thinking it is a foreign key if for
>   some reason data ceases to exist on one end?

Foreign keys are critical to enforcing [referential integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity).

For example, if you had `field_id` as a foreign key in the `texts` table, you couldn't delete the corresponding record from the `field` table (without using `cascade` to delete downstream records as well), since it's referring to a record in `field`.

On the flip side, you wouldn't be able to insert into `texts` a row with an invalid `field_id` -- if `field_id` didn't exist in `fields`, *Postgres* would throw a *foreign-key constraint violation*.

Foreign keys are critical pieces of a table design, and should definitely be utilized. It saves you from having to put all of that logic all over the place in your application code, e.g. having to check to see if the keys you're about to insert are valid before trying to insert anything; instead, if they're not, *Postgres* will violate the constraint, and that comes back to your app as an exception that can be handled, such as rolling back and returning an error).

Basically, any time you have an id in one table that refers to a record in another table, that should be defined in a foreign key constraint.

Also, it would probably be worth adding a *primary key* to each table. I often like to use a `serial` variable to ensure each row is identifiable by a single key, even if there are tuples which form implied primary keys. Primary keys also implicitly create indexes based on those keys.

Comment: Hi.  I've been looking into the SchemaPlus gem, and it seems to be add foreign constraints as a simple convention that I can put in my migrations.  Are there any issues with just making all of the columns I intended to be foreign keys officially such? Like are there issues caused by thinking it is a foreign key if for some reason data ceases to exist on one end? I have some rows that will reference my main users table, and could be a key, but they are also able to be deleted.  Would a foreign key cause any ripple effects in deletion?